# Laravel Dompdf attachment coming Unable to JSON encode payload. Error code: 5

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I have written below code in Mail/Mails.php file build function.

```
return $this->from(config('app.FROM_EMAIL'),config('app.MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
                    ->subject($this->subject)
                    ->view('emails.generalmail')
                    ->attachData($this->attach,'file_pdf.pdf');
```

**Error**

> Unable to JSON encode payload. Error code: 5

I used Dompdf email send with attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Laravel you are on so it could be slightly different but you need to use the `attach` function rather than `attachData`

```
return $this->from(config('app.FROM_EMAIL'),config('app.MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
                    ->subject($this->subject)
                    ->view('emails.generalmail')
                    ->attach('[PATH TO FILE]');
```

See more here: [Laravel Mail Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#attachments)

Change the version at the top.

Comment: Thank you but i want without store in folder.

Comment: You'll need to store it temporarily somewhere to send as an attachment

Comment: Okay so not possible without store ?

Comment: Nope unfortunately not

Comment: Could you mark the answer as the correct one when you have a moment, it'll help future people when they have a similar problem even if it doesn't solve your problem directly

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without saving the file to disk using the function
`->attachData($this->attach,'file_pdf.pdf')`. The error is thrown because php doesnt know how to serialize the binary pdf file data to json. What you need to do is generate the data `$this->attach` in your mail files handle function, not the constructor. That way php doesnt have to serialize it:

````
```
public function handle() {
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf_view', $data);
    return $this->from(config('app.FROM_EMAIL'),config('app.MAIL_FROM_NAME'))
        ->subject($this->subject)
        ->view('emails.generalmail')
        ->attachData($pdf->output(),'file_pdf.pdf');
}```
````